# Minecraft Mob Killing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently working on a futuristic apocalyptic Minecraft map. If the player presses a button the apocalypse starts. Every 10-20 seconds or so (don't know the exact time...), 4 new zombies are summoned on each of the spawning sites. Now, here is my problem. It would require a god-like PvPer in order to keep the amount of zombies from becoming so high that lag eventually would crash the server. Hence my idea was to kill a certain amount of zombies every 20 seconds or so. Is there any way to do so? If not, do you have any alternative solutions? 
Thank you in advance! (I might publish the map when I complete it...)

Comment: So far I haven't tried anything xD

Answer (score 0):

Make a score called killZombieTimer or something, and make it stat.playOneMinute. Then have a chain of two commands. The first command will kill 15 zombies when a player has played for 20 seconds, `/execute @a[score_killZombieTimer_min=400] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=zombie,c=15]`. The second command will reset the score, `/scoreboard players reset @a[score_killZombieTimer_min=400] killZombieTimer`.

Comment: Ooh! Thanks! I suppose I could just hook a command block up to a repeating redstone clock that sends a pulse every 20 seconds, then? I didn't know the c= thing existed xD It stands for count or something, right?

Comment: Yeah, a repeating command block. Also, yeah, c is count.

Comment: Thanks! - I ended up just summoning a zombie with a different name among all the other zombies. Every pulse of my clock it teleports itself along with 6 other zombies within a radius of 30 blocks into the void. It seems to regulate the lag fairly well.

Comment: execute @e[name=AntiLag] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=Zombie,r=30,c=5] ~ ~-70 ~